# How to create a 3D array to json and parse it?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I try to combine 2 tables of database to a json object, I think it is maybe a 3D array

like this↓

table_1 ->(name:"Ken"),(gender:"male")

table_2 ->(name:"Lon"),(gender:"male")

table_1 and 2 is 1st dimension, name and gender is 2nd dimension, 
ken and male is 3rd dimension

so, I made a json object wiht PHP "json_encode()", and try to parse it with javascript

json object：

```
{
"client_infos":[ {
    "client": {
        "no": 1, "C_name": "ken", "input_date": "2017-07-20 13:44:46", "total_price": 123
    }
    ,
    "item_lists":[["item_list",
    {
        "no": 1, "rs_no": 1, "item_name": "ApplePie", "item_quantity": 2, "unit_price": 10
    }
    ],
    ["item_list",
    {
        "no": 2, "rs_no": 1, "item_name": "BananaCow", "item_quantity": 3, "unit_price": 5
    }
    ]]
}
,
{
    "client": {
        "no": 3, "C_name": "ken", "input_date": "2017-07-20 14:24:26", "total_price": 200
    }
    ,
    "item_lists":[["item_list",
    {
        "no": 5, "rs_no": 3, "item_name": "LimeMilk", "item_quantity": 5, "unit_price": 33
    }
    ]]
}
]
```

}

how do I parse it ? 
for example, I want to extract the data of 2nd client and item_lists.

I have been using JSON.parse(json), but I have no idea how to get the value.

```
var content = JSON.parse(res);
console.log(content.client_infos.client[1].no);
```

it's not work.

Comment: How do you parse it with what? PHP? [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode). Javascript? It depends on how the JS is getting it, which you haven't shown. Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var object = JSON.parse(variableOrStringLiteral);
```

Answer (score 0):

finally, I find out the right way to get the value that like this

```
var obj = JSON.parse(content);
obj.client_infos[0].client.no;
```